# onClick anonymous function with arguments vs onClick(function(arguments))

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know why in certain types of events, such as `onClick`, I have to declare an anonymous function to execute the `onClick` if my function contains arguments.

**Example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-ramanujan-v998u

```
export default function App() {

  const myValue = "MY VALUE";

  
  const handleClick = (anyString) => {
    console.log(anyString);
  };
  

  const anotherClick = () => {
    console.log("It works");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => anotherClick()} color="primary">
        Works without arguments <-- Works
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={anotherClick} color="secondary">
        Works without arguments <-- Works
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={() => handleClick(myValue)} color="primary">
        Works with arguments <-- Works
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClick(myValue)} color="secondary">
        Does NOT work with arguments <-- Does NOT work
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Question**
I do not understand why I have to create an anonymous function if the function I want to execute has arguments.

Why do I have to do `onClick={() => handleClick(myString)`}?

Why `onClick={handleClick(myString)}` is not enough?

Comment: because you are executing the function and assigning what it returns to the click handler. Did you not see it was called right away?

Comment: `onClick={handleClick(myString)}` calls the function immediately (during the render) and attempts to assign the returned value to `onClick`; whereas `onClick={() => handleClick(myString)` **passes** a function reference that will then be called on click.

Comment: Also an important note - `onClick={anotherClick}` is not equivalent to `onClick={anotherClick()}` (for the same reason as the above comments). The following parenthesis that signal the function should be called is a very important distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onClick` accepts a callback i.e. a function that will be called when the button is clicked.

1. `anotherClick` is a function so it works, as it's being called properly
2. `() => anotherClick()` is equivalent to this

```js
...
const myTempFunction = () => {
  anotherClick();
}
...
onClick={myTempFunction}
```

Since you're ultimately passing a function to `onClick` it works

3. `() => handleClick(myValue)` same reason as above, and equivalent code is

```js
...
const myTempFunction = () => {
  handleClick(myValue);
}
...
onClick={myTempFunction}
```

4. `handleClick(myValue)`, now here you're actually calling the function the you're passing the *value* that the function returns to `onClick`, not the function itself,
   the equivalent code would be

```js
...
const myResult = handleClick(myValue); // This is the result of calling the function
...
onClick={myResult} // myResult isn't a function, it's the return value of handleClick(myValue)
```

Since you're not actually passing a function to `onClick`, `onClick` can't be called and it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

This is due to design of the syntax extension what we called JSX Template extension. When it comes to event Handling inside JSX, it needs a `reference` to the callback function which is going to trigger after specific event happens.

This is before JSX is converted in to JavaScript Via Babel

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={anotherClick} color="secondary">
        Works without arguments
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClick(myValue)} color="secondary">
        Does NOT work with arguments 
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
```

This is after the Babel Conversion.

```
  return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(Button, {
          onClick: anotherClick,
          color: "secondary"
        }, "Works without arguments"), 
         React.createElement(Button, {
          onClick: handleClick(myValue),
          color: "secondary"
        }, "Does NOT work with arguments"));
```

You can clearly see here that second click handler is executing the function directly rather than passing a callback function to `React.createElement`. Because internally React Element need a callback function to get pass to this function and you are just try to execute that function instead of parsing the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to specify a function in `onClick={func}`. "func" is only referring to a variable.

When saying `onClick={func()}`, you are adding the return value of `func()`, rather than specifying `function func() { }` to be executed, when the event is emitted.

When the button is clicked, the function, specified in `onClick={}` is executed.
This is what you are doing:

```
let emit = function () { };
button.addEventListener('click', emit());
```

When the button is clicked, it tries to call `undefined` as a function, since the function emit() has returned `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

In the doc for ([Handling Component Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)), there is an example

```
function ActionLink() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </a>
  );
}
```

So we could see that every value passed to event handler props (`onClick`, `onFocus`,...) must be a method (or you may say function)

Go back to your example, in the first 3, you pass function, so it definitely works. But with the 4th, first to say `handleClick` is simply a method that return `undefined`, so when you call `onClick={handleClick(myValue)}`, it similar to `onClick={undefined}`, which resulted in nothing happened

```js
const handleClick = (anyString) => {
  console.log(anyString);
};
// ...
<Button onClick={handleClick(myValue)} color="secondary">
  Does NOT work with arguments <-- Does NOT work
</Button>
```