# Why doesn't React render an element without function invoked by arrow function unlike normal onClick functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does this work?

```
<span onClick={()=>removeTodo(index)}>x</span>
```

But this doesn't work?

```
<span onClick={removeTodo(index)}>x</span>
```

Full code

```
{todo.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <pre className={index} key={index}>
      <h1 id={array}>{item}</h1>
      <span onClick={()=>removeTodo(index)}>x</span>
    </pre>
);
})}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick calling functions diffrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71245336/onclick-calling-functions-diffrences)

Comment: Because the function is executed instantly when the JSX is compiled. So the `removeTodo(index)` is being replaced by its return value, which is most likely `undefined` (void).

Comment: also: [onClick anonymous function with arguments vs onClick(function(arguments))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455337/onclick-anonymous-function-with-arguments-vs-onclickfunctionarguments)

Comment: Functions are data types in JavaScript and just like you can't give a `boolean` where you expect a `string`, you can't pass a `string` where you expect a function. `onClick` expects a function to be executed later and assigning the result of a function invocation to it will only work if the function returns another function, which your function probably doesn't. Note that you don't HAVE to pass an arrow function or a NEW function, you can also pass the existing function by name, like `removeTodo`, but due to arguments to the function this is not always possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onClick function requires a short hand function syntax `()=>{}` especially when you are calling a function and passing the parameters at the same time. It is also used when you are calling multiple functions inside onClick.

**When to Use `()=>` in onClick?**

1. Calling a function with a parameter
2. Calling multiple function in a single onClick
3. Providing a function definition inside onClick

**When not to use?**

- Calling a function without a parameter